# Get the value of a result list in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working with Javascript to perform a select option

I get the result from a function like this

```
.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "getEcran",
    data : {
        idType : theme
    },
    success : function(result) {
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        ...
```

The result of the Post method is a list, each element of the list have his own list

My question is I try to access the second list but it always shows `undefined`.

I tried to access my second list like that :

```
if(result[i].type == "Select Simple"){      
     alert(result[i].listTompo);

     var p = result[i].listTompo ;
     var x ;
     for(x in p ){
        alert(x.value);
     }
```

Comment: you can use developer tools, and use console, example when you get the result, make console.log(result), and show to use what kind of information are you retreiving from the server, and then we can help :)

Comment: Please share the response

Comment: I've just share it @brk

Comment: @YagamiLight i cannot find it anywhere

Comment: What do you mean by `i cannot find it anywhere` ?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the method that i show in the question, i've acces the data with this one :

```
for(var j = 0 ; j < result[i].listTompo.length ; j++ ){
    alert(result[i].listTompo[j].valeur);
}
```

Thank you every one for your help.

Comment: @brk this is my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `json` as response so you have to use [dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `dataType:'json'` in your AJAX options like,

```
.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "getEcran",
    data : {
        idType : theme
    },
    dataType:'json', // add this to get json response
    success : function(result) {
```

Alternatively, you can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) before using it in your success callback.

Comment: After getting the `Json Response`  can i access the data ?!? it's showing undifined

Comment: I've found a better solution thank you for your help

Comment: @brk, yes it is not compulsory as the response is `string` by default. But OP has required to traverse the array of objects which needs to be parsed using dataType:json or JSON.parse().